# Web development editor with live preview with bi-directional edit support

Tags: web-development

I was wondering if anyone knows any editor suitable for web development that supports live previews similar to [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) (i.e. update preview not just after saving a file, but also whenever a change is detected in a HTML, CSS or JS file linked to the preview).

Also, besides supporting functionality similar to Espresso's live preview, it'd be great if it'd allow to use inspect element in an internal or external browser, make changes via inspect element and have those changes reflect back in the text file without saving (similar to [Emmet LiveStyle](http://livestyle.io/))

Any pointers?